# Get AD ID information from LDAP

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2003

I use the following code for a web ASP.net application and locally it works fine but on the server it doesn't. It returns an error saying "Table does not exist". In my web config I've put `<identity impersonate="true"/>`

Any ideas?

```
#Region " Get AD ID information from LDAP"
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objRootDSE, objRecordSet, objCommand, objConnection, strDNSDomain As Object
    Dim strQuery, strBase, strFilter, strAttributes As Object
    Dim intCountNumber As Integer

    Try
        ' Determine DNS domain name from RootDSE object.
        objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
        strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")

        ' Use ADO to search Active Directory.
        objRecordSet = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
        objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        objConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
        objConnection.Open("Active Directory Provider")
        objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

        strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"
        strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" & TB_UserID.Text & "))"
        strAttributes = "sn,givenname,mail,telephoneNumber,"
        strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
        objCommand.CommandText = strQuery
        objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute
        intCountNumber = objRecordSet.Fields.Count
        TB_Name.Text = objRecordSet.Fields("givenname").value
        TB_LastName.Text = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("sn").value
        TB_Email.Text = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("mail").value
        TB_Telephone.Text = objRecordSet.Fields.Item("telephoneNumber").value

        objRecordSet = Nothing
        objConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        DisplayWebMsgBox.WebMsgBox.MessageBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

## End Region

Answer (score 0):

I found out that with the provider "ADsDSOObject", it uses the user creditentials to run LDAP search. So from the server side it could not work unless I provide a username and password creditentials.

```
    objConnection.Properties("User ID") = Username
objConnection.Properties("Password") = Password
 objConnection.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
```